# Find the derivative of this function using chain rule or product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative of $f(x)$$=$$10^{x^2+2}$

Can anybody help me try to solve this through the chain rule?

I have tried using the chain rule and exponent rule I figured out that

$f(x)=10^x$ the derivative is $f'(x)=ln(10)10^x$

$g(x) = x^2+2$ the derivative is $g'(x) = 2x$

Hence my answer for this derivative of function f(x) was
$f'(x) = (2x)(ln(10))(10^{x^2+2})$

however on the calculator/wolfram alpha it says that the answer is

[image]

I am unsure what the next steps to take to confirm which one is the right derivative.

Comment: $10^{x^2+2}=2^{x^2+2}5^{x^2+2}$.

Comment: you mean $2^{x^2+3}$ ?

Comment: There are no more steps for you to take. These answers are the same. Note that WolframAlpha (and many scientific articles and pieces of scientific software) use $\log$ to denote $\ln$. And the $2$ in your $2x$ term got absorbed into the exponent: $$
(2x)(10^{x^2+2}) = (2x)(2^{x^2+2}\times 5^{x^2+2}) = x\left(2^{x^2+3} \times 5^{x^2+2}\right)$$

Comment: thank you i was not sure since it was very complicated

Comment: To reach that use the $2$ which in the front of all the expression.

Comment: thank you for clarifying

Comment: If something gives you a different looking answer verify whether they actually *are* different. $2^{x^2 + 3}\times 5^{x^2 + 2} = 2\cdot 2^{x^2+2}5^{x^2 + 2} = 2\cdot (2\times 5)^{x^2+2} = 2\times 10^{x^2 + 2}$.  Wolfram, being a machine and not a human being prime factorized and getting an exatra $2$ got different powers.  A dumb machine will think $2^7\times 5^6$ is clearer and more basic than $2\times 10^6$.   But a smart human will know that $2\times 10^6$ has more *meaning*.  But either way $2^7\cdot 5^6 = 2\cdot 10^6$ so they are both the same.

Comment: tl;dr.   Wolfram seeing $2*10^{x^2+2}$ sees that $2$ and $10$ have factors in common and the programmers felt to handle everything that might come its way figures they should program in a rule the the same prime factors should be grouped together (otherwise we could be stupid results such as $2^6\times 5^4\times 10^7\times 15^2$) so it figure was should factor the $2$ out   $2\times 10^{x^2+2} = 2\times 2^{x^2+2}\times 5^{x^2+2}=2^{x^2 + 3}5^{x^2+2}$.  We human see nothing wrong with $2\times 10^{x^2+2}$.  It's just "we take $10$ to a power and multiply it by $2$".  Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score -2):

You did it correctly and got the same answer as Wolfram did.

When Wolfram writes "$\log$" it means the natural log.  (That's common, but confusing as hell, practice).

Wolfram wrote $2^{x^2+3}\times 5^{x^2 + 2}x \log 10$ and meant $2^{x^2+3}\times 5^{x^2 + 2}x \ln 10$ and you got $(2x)(ln(10))(10^{x^2+2})$.

what's the difference?

Actually nothing.

$2^{x^2+3}\times 5^{x^2 + 2}x \ln 10 =$

$2\cdot 2^{x^2 + 2}\times 5^{x^2 + 2} x \ln 10=$

$2(2\times 5)^{x^2 + 2}  x\ln 10=$

$2\cdot 10^{x^2+2} x \ln 10$

which, order and parenthesis aside, is exactly what you got.

So you did jes' fine.

Comment: It's not that OP couldn't do this, he wrote this exactly in his post - he didn't understand why Wolfram's answer was different (both forms are actually equivalent, as people have pointed out in the comments)

Comment: Yeah.... I saw that later and ... answered in the comments.